# Go Back N question(netwrok)

Tags: communication-protocols, protocols

Hello I am trying to understand the GBN protocol and I encountered the following question during my homework.

Assume that we have GBN protocol with a window size of **20**. The **sender** sends 15 packets one after the other with seq numbers from 1-15. After that, the sender is waiting to get acks from the **server** (the **sender**  doesn't have any more info yet).

Now Firstly ack #3 arrives then ack #7 arrives and then ack #11 arrives. 
after that, we get a TIME-OUT.

the question is: in response to that T.O mentioned above the **the sender will send ----- packets**

As I understand after we get the 11th ack we know that everything before has been working just fine.

But I'm getting confused with the window size and the sequence number of the messages.

Please anyone can explain and help.

Thanks.

Comment: since timeout has occurred it will follow slow start phase till n/2 window size, i.e. 5 in this case and after that it will increment by 1 mss

Comment: Moreover the question is a bit ambiguous, as u are saying that the window size is 20, but here we can see that an acknowlegement is sent after every 4th packet and in GBN we sent  cumulative acknowledgement after each window, so I think the window size should be 4 rather than 20, and 20 is the total number fo packets that we are trying too send

Comment: Sorry but I dont know why you say  it will follow slow start phase till n/2 any reference?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/computer-network-tcp-congestion-control/